# NestWhile question, ensuring a function is repeatedly applied to a newly set input-value

Tags: parameters

**Problem:** I need to ensure that a function which is repeatedly called in NestWhile correctly uses a newly computed input on its next call. I will give the context while omitting parts of the code (which is irrelevant to state the problem).

**Context:** I am coding a "push-up operation" on an integer labelled Hasse diagram. The integer labels are distinct from one another and must form a topological sort on the Hasse diagram *with the exception of one minimal vertex v* (minimal in the Hasse diagram order). This vertex can have an arbitrary integer label ***a***. The label ***a*** needs to be pushed up in the Hasse diagram so that the final result forms a topological sort.

If the vertex ***v*** has successor vertices then the label ***a*** is "swapped up" as long as ***a*** is strictly greater than the minimum label ***m*** on the success vertices of ***v***. In that case ***a*** is swapped with ***m***, so ***a*** ends up as label of the relevant successor vertex of  ***v***. The label ***a*** keeps being swapped up in this way in the Hasse diagram until it ends up on a vertex ***w*** for which ***a*** is strictly below the labels of the successor vertices of ***w***.

**The Code:** I implemented a function ***swapUp***. It carries out a single swap operation, exchanging the label of a vertex ***v*** with the minimal label occurring on the successor vertices of ***v***.

The code uses weights and labels and colours on these and I won't repeat it here. The problem I encounter is basic (and related to parameter passing errors).

***swapUp*** takes as input a labelled Hasse diagram represented by state_ and a vertex v_

```
swapUp[state_, v_] :=
 Module[{minLabel, minSuccessor}, *rest of code*]
```

I want to use ***swapUp*** as part of ***NestWhile*** to ensure that the swapUp operations keep happening on the newly create state and on the selected successor vertex (until the condition is met).

The problem I have is related to parameter passing.

I tried using an assignment of ***v*** to one of its selected successor vertices. This gives an error of the kind: "cannot pass to raw object".

```
swapUp[state_, v_] :=
 Module[{minLabel, minSuccessor}, *rest of code*, v = selected-successor-vertex-of-v]
```

I wonder if the assignment

```
v = selected-successor-vertex-of-v
```

needs to be replaced with something that uses a rule:

```
v -> selected-successor-vertex-of-v
```

How do you ensure that at the end of the swapUp code(as part of the Module body) the vertex v is reset to its selected successor, so that a repeated call to swapUp (in NestWhile) starts from the correct (successor) vertex? The next swapUp needs to use the newly produced state (i.e. the Hasse diagram with swapped labels produced as part of the previous swapUp) but also operate over the selected successor vertex of v.

I will post all parts of the code in case the above outline turns out to be insufficient.

Comment: Well, first off, yes, the assignment `v=...`will fail since `v` is an argument to the function but not a variable (i.e. not something that you can use Set on). But I'm not really sure if that's actually your main question...

Comment: Since `swapUp[state_, v_]` has two arguments, when you do NestWhile you're going to have to play games to get it to work. It would be much easier if `swapUp` took a single argument that was a pair: `swapUp[state_, v_]`. Next issue is that NestWhile wants to apply the given function to the result each time. That means taht `swapUp` should return a pair: `{nextState, nextV}`. I don't know how you need to calculate those things.

Comment: @lericr How do you return a pair? Is there a return statement (akin to Python)?

Comment: I should maybe add to my first comment a bit... There shouldn't be any reason to do an assignment to `v` anyway. You don't care about that `v` after you use it--you can just "throw it away". You need to figure out how to calculate the successor `v` (and return it as the second member of the pair).

Comment: Sure, I can compute successors. I have written that code part. I am not sure how to return a pair at the end (or explicitly return any value for that matter) at the end

Comment: Since you're using Module (which, by the way, it's not at all clear that that is necessary, but that's another conversation), just know that the last expression in the body of the Module is what is "returned". So, `Module[{},"hello"]` will "return" the string "hello". I put "return" in quotes because we dont think of this as a return like from a procedure call. It is simply the result of the evaluation of the expression.

Comment: So, `Module[{},{1,3}]` will return `{1,3}`.

Comment: Ah darn that simple. Of course. Will try it, thanks

Comment: Okay, just to head off any confusion, I probably should have been more accurate than saying Module returns the "last expression". The body of the Module is a single expression, and that expression gets evaluated. It is very typical to see the body of a Module to be a CompoundExpression. This happens to look like a sequence of expressions because it is usually written with infix `;`. And CompoundExpression evaluates to its last expression.

Comment: So, `Module[{},a;b;c]` is really `Module[{},CompoundExpression[a,b,c]]`. The expressions `a`, `b`, and `c` will be evaluated, but the entire compound expression will evaluate to whatever `c` evaluated to.

Comment: Hmm, just looked back at my earlier comments. I somehow lost the critical `{}`. You want swapUp to be defined for a form like this: `swapUp[{state_,v_}]`. Sorry, that was very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only a very partial answer to try to clarify how the NestWhile could work.

Say you have

```
theFunc[{a_, b_}] := {2 a, b/2}
```

then you can use Nest with theFunc directly (NestWhile is the same for the relevant part):

```
Nest[theFunc, {128, 128}, 5]
(* {4096, 4} *)
```

It's not quite as nice if your arguments don't come in pairs, like this

```
otherFunc[a_, b_] := {2 a, b/2}
```

but you have a couple of choices. First you can use Apply:

```
Nest[Apply[otherFunc], {128, 128}, 5]
(* {4096, 4} *)
```

or you can add a new definition for otherFunc:

```
otherFunc[{a_, b_}] := otherFunc[a, b];
Nest[otherFunc, {128, 128}, 5]
(* {4096, 4} *)
```

Things get hairier still if your output has a different shape than your input:

```
crazyFunc[{a_, b_}] := a + 7 b;
Nest[{#[[1]], crazyFunc[#]} &, {2, 1}, 5]
(* {2, 22409} *)
```

Here I wanted to keep the first element of the pair constant and re-use it on each call to update the second pair.

And so on...

Comment: Thanks! That's great