# Setting up the function for a NestWhile application produces the wrong result due to vertex assignment requirement. How can it be fixed?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I received advice [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274101/nestwhile-question-ensuring-a-function-is-repeatedly-applied-to-a-newly-set-inp/274107#274107) to set up a function used in NestWhile so that the function "returns" the correct result at the end (in order for its next call in NestWhile to operate on the correct input). This is achieved by adding a final expression in the function expression containing the desired input for the next call. This is the expression `{state, maxPredecessor}` in swapDown2 below.

I include two definitions of a function intended to swap two labels in a graph: swapDown1 and swapDown 2. The first version does not contain the additional expression discussed above. The second version does.

The function swapDown1 executes correctly as illustrated below ***once*** the variable ***state*** explicitly is assigned the result of swapDown1 after the execution of this function. This is necessary since for graphs the contents of the variable ***state*** are not automatically updated. This issue unfortunately seems to clash with the advice given on producing return values in preparation for a NestWhile application. There must be a work-around and I would be grateful for any suggestions.

How can I combine both approaches (the need to reset the variable state after the computation of swapDown1 and the need to return ***state*** before this assignment is carried out)?

When the function is set up to serve as a function in NestWhile (as done in swapDown2 below) using the above approach of adding the values to be "returned" as a pair, the function ceases to execute the swap.

I display all code below, but only the last line of swapDown2 (not contained in swapDown1) is relevant as well as the assignment to the variable state following swapDown1.

```
vf[{xc_, yc_}, name_, {w_, h_}] := 
  Block[{xmin = xc - w, xmax = xc + w, ymin = yc - h, ymax = yc + h}, 
   Polygon[{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymin}}]];

paintBlue[x_] := Style[x, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]

bareLabels[labelList_] := #[[1]] & /@ labelList

blueSPLabels[g_, vertexSublist_] := #[[1]][[2]] & /@ 
  vertexLabelsOnSublist[g, vertexSublist]

vertexLabel[g_, v_] := AnnotationValue[{g, v}, VertexLabels]
vertexLabelsOnSublist[g_, lis_] := vertexLabel[g, #] & /@ lis

vertexLabelsOnSublist[g_, lis_] := vertexLabel[g, #] & /@ lis

predecessorVertices[g_, v_] := Rest[VertexInComponent[g, v, 1]]

predecessorLabels[g_, v_] := 
 vertexLabelsOnSublist[g, predecessorVertices[g, v]]

predecessorSPLabels[g_, v_] :=  
 blueSPLabels[g, predecessorVertices[g, v]]

swapDown1[{state_, v_}] :=
 Module[{maxLabel, maxPredecessor},
  maxLabel = {}; maxPredecessor = {};
  If[predecessorVertices[state, v] != {},
   maxLabel = paintBlue[Max[bareLabels[
       predecessorSPLabels[state, v]   ]]]]; 
  If[predecessorVertices[state, v] != {}, 
   maxPredecessor = 
    Select[predecessorVertices[state, v], 
      blueSPLabels[state, {#}][[1]] == paintBlue[Max[bareLabels[
           predecessorSPLabels[state, v]      ]]] &] [[1]] ];
  If[maxLabel === {},
   {v -> AnnotationValue[{state, v}, VertexLabels]}, {v -> 
     Placed[{AnnotationValue[{state, v}, VertexLabels][[1]][[1]], 
       maxLabel}, {Before, After}], 
    maxPredecessor -> 
     Placed[{AnnotationValue[{state, maxPredecessor}, VertexLabels][[
         1]][[1]], 
       AnnotationValue[{state, v}, VertexLabels][[1]][[2]]}, {Before, 
       After}]}]]

swapDown2[{state_, v_}] :=
 Module[{maxLabel, maxPredecessor},
  maxLabel = {}; maxPredecessor = {};
  If[predecessorVertices[state, v] != {},
   maxLabel = paintBlue[Max[bareLabels[
       predecessorSPLabels[state, v]   ]]]]; 
  If[predecessorVertices[state, v] != {}, 
   maxPredecessor = 
    Select[predecessorVertices[state, v], 
      blueSPLabels[state, {#}][[1]] == paintBlue[Max[bareLabels[
           predecessorSPLabels[state, v]      ]]] &] [[1]] ];
  If[maxLabel === {},
   {v -> AnnotationValue[{state, v}, VertexLabels]}, {v -> 
     Placed[{AnnotationValue[{state, v}, VertexLabels][[1]][[1]], 
       maxLabel}, {Before, After}], 
    maxPredecessor -> 
     Placed[{AnnotationValue[{state, maxPredecessor}, VertexLabels][[
         1]][[1]], 
       AnnotationValue[{state, v}, VertexLabels][[1]][[2]]}, {Before, 
       After}]}]; {state, maxPredecessor}]
```

Consider an assignment to state below.

```
state = Graph[
 {1, 2, 3, 4},
 {DirectedEdge[1, 3], DirectedEdge[1, 4], DirectedEdge[2, 3], DirectedEdge[2, 4]}, 
 {
  FormatType -> TraditionalForm, ImageSize -> {240, 240}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0., -1.}, {1., -1.}, {0., 0.}, {1., 0.}}, 
  VertexLabels -> {3 -> Placed[{Style[3, Red], Style[4, Blue]}, {Before, After}], 
    4 -> Placed[{Style[4, Red], Style[3, Blue]}, {Before, After}], 
    2 -> Placed[{Style[2, Red], Style[2, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]}, {Before, After}],
    1 -> Placed[{Style[1, Red], Style[1, Blue]}, {Before, After}]},
  VertexShapeFunction -> {vf}, VertexWeight -> {1, 2, 3, 4}
 }]
```

This produces the graph:

[image]

Next, carry out the instruction: `SetProperty[state, VertexLabels -> swapDown1[{state, 4}]]`

[image]

This does not produce the desired result, which can be checked by entering ***state*** in Mathematica. This produces the original image.

```
state
```

[image]

SetProperty fails to assign the new labels. A separate assignment needs to be carried out to ensure the variable is updated:

```
state = SetProperty[state, VertexLabels -> swapDown1[{state, 4}]]
```

This produces (when ***state*** is entered):

[image]

swapDown2 which is set up to be part of a NestWhile does not produce the correct result.

To see this, clear the state variable (of which a picture of the graph stored in this variable was included above) and reset state to the graph (of which the code is displayed above).

The result is again:

[image]

Carry out swapDown2:

```
SetProperty[state, VertexLabels -> swapDown2[{state, 4}]]
```

This produces:

[image]

Finally:

```
state = SetProperty[state, VertexLabels -> swapDown2[{state, 4}]]
```

Produces a result that does not have the intended label swap:

[image]

How can I combine both setting up the function swapDown for use in Nestwhile (by adding the final result expression  `{state, maxPredecessor}` while also assigning state to the correct swapped result so that NestWhile operates correctly when repeatedly applying swaps in this way?

I followed the advice given and tried:

```
swapDown3[{state_, v_}] :=
 Module[{maxLabel, maxPredecessor},
  maxLabel = {}; maxPredecessor = {};
  If[predecessorVertices[state, v] != {},
   maxLabel = paintBlue[Max[bareLabels[
       predecessorSPLabels[state, v]   ]]]]; 
  If[predecessorVertices[state, v] != {}, 
   maxPredecessor = 
    Select[predecessorVertices[state, v], 
      blueSPLabels[state, {#}][[1]] == paintBlue[Max[bareLabels[
           predecessorSPLabels[state, v]      ]]] &] [[1]] ];
  {SetProperty[state, If[maxLabel === {},
     {v -> AnnotationValue[{state, v}, VertexLabels]}, {v -> 
       Placed[{AnnotationValue[{state, v}, VertexLabels][[1]][[1]], 
         maxLabel}, {Before, After}], 
      maxPredecessor -> 
       Placed[{AnnotationValue[{state, maxPredecessor}, 
            VertexLabels][[1]][[1]], 
         AnnotationValue[{state, v}, VertexLabels][[1]][[
          2]]}, {Before, After}]}]], maxPredecessor}]
```

However, when running

```
swapDown3[{state, 4}]
```

or even

```
state = swapDown3[{state, 4}][[1]]
```

the swap is still not executed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I keep trying to follow this but I lose the plot halfway through. Can you pare this down any?

Comment: Okay, I've been trying to get your code to execute by manually creating suitable graphs, and it's just a pain. I don't think you're going to get any traction for your question if you can't provide working code (that is copyable--don't expect people to manually retype data from an image) and a clear explanation of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Instead of returning `state`, return `SetProperty[state, XXX]`, where `XXX` is what you're returning from `swapDown1` (i.e. the entire last `If`). That way, you're returning the modified version of state to be further modified by subsequent calls

Comment: @lericr I replaced the snapshot of the code by code that can be coped.

Comment: @LukasLang I followed your advice via code for swapDown3 (included now in the question). It still does not carry out the swap.

Comment: @Michel Your attempt is almost correct, you simply forgot the `VertexLabels->` part in the `SetProperty` call inside `stateDown3`. (When writing my previous comment, I failed to notice that you were including `VertexLabels->` in your manual `SetProperty` calls, so I didn't include it)

Comment: Thank you that sorted it. If you'd like to add it as an answer, I will give it a check mark. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning state, return `SetProperty[state, VertexLabels->XXX]`, where `XXX` is what you're returning from `swapDown1` (i.e. the entire last `If`). That way, you're returning the modified version of `state` to be further modified by subsequent calls:

```
swapDown3[{state_, v_}] := 
 Module[{maxLabel, maxPredecessor}, maxLabel = {}; maxPredecessor = {};
  If[predecessorVertices[state, v] != {}, 
   maxLabel = 
    paintBlue[Max[bareLabels[predecessorSPLabels[state, v]]]]];
  If[predecessorVertices[state, v] != {}, 
   maxPredecessor = 
    Select[predecessorVertices[state, v], 
      blueSPLabels[state, {#}][[1]] == 
        paintBlue[
         Max[bareLabels[predecessorSPLabels[state, v]]]] &][[1]]];
  {SetProperty[state, 
    VertexLabels -> 
     If[maxLabel === {}, {v -> 
        AnnotationValue[{state, v}, VertexLabels]}, {v -> 
        Placed[{AnnotationValue[{state, v}, VertexLabels][[1]][[1]], 
          maxLabel}, {Before, After}], 
       maxPredecessor -> 
        Placed[{AnnotationValue[{state, maxPredecessor}, 
             VertexLabels][[1]][[1]], 
          AnnotationValue[{state, v}, 
             VertexLabels][[1]][[2]]}, {Before, After}]}]], 
   maxPredecessor}]
```

Now it works as it should (using `state` and the other definitions from the question):

```
swapDown3[{state, 4}]
```

[image]